# I have doubts with understanding the following section

Tags: definite-article

Stack Exchange ["How do I write a good answer?"](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) has the following section:

> #### Pay it forward
>
> Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but *it doesn’t answer the question*. Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

While I understand the meaning of the header and mostly understand the meaning of the whole section, I had a discussion about interpretation of the emphasized "**it doesn’t answer the question**" phrase with my friend.

My friend treated that as "*we should not say 'thank you' in our answers*". My original interpretation was like "*…but just saying 'thank you', per se, doesn't aid (or aid not so much) in resolving other questions from the question flow*". But then I started to doubt: why did they used "***the** question*" (instead of, for example, "***a** question*", "***any** question*", "***other** questions*", "*questions **in general***" or etc), does it mean that they refer some aforementioned/implied question? (That would break my interpretation.)

So:

- Is my interpretation correct?
- If yes — what are reasonable explanations for using "the" in that case (what *aforementioned/implied* question does the text refer)? If no — what should be the correct interpretation of the "*…but it doesn’t answer the question*"?

Comment: *"How do I write a good answer?"* in your first line is misleading. It's a *different* "FAQ" in a more general list of things relating to SO "Answers". But I think whoever wrote that part of the Help section was getting a bit confused himself. What he means is the *Original Poster* (the OP) shouldn't just post a comment saying "Thanks" under whatever he thinks is a good answer (it's just "noise" - what *really* matters is that you should *upvote* good answers and *accept* the best one). And you should express thanks to the whole community *by posting answers yourself*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, sorry, why misleading?

Comment: There's no good reason to include "thanks" (in advance) in an SO *question* (myself and some other users often edit to delete them). And it would rarely make sense to include anything like that in an Answer either. The point in the Help text about "Thanks!" *in a comment* not answering the question is simply a result of muddled thinking - obviously it doesn't answer anything, but the writer appears to be specifically talking about the situation where the OP writes that. He should have said that *Thanks for asking this question! I too am interested in the answer!* is a pretty worthless comment.

Comment: (i.e. - don't *thank* people for asking a good question. ***Upvote*** it.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ah, I understand, there is [another text](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659) with the same name. But I don't mislead, [the text I referred to](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) also has the same name. (Oops, this was my reply your first comment, I'm reading further now.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I understand the policies in general. I was asking specific about what that phrase ("…, but it doesn’t answer the question") stands exactly for in this specific text.

Comment: I think the bottom line is that section of text you're asking about is simply "muddled". ***It*** refers to the practice of writing things like ***Thanks*** (in a Question, Answer, or comment; it's contextually unclear what the writer had in mind). Which doesn't answer ***the*** Question (the one someone posted, causing the relevant web page to exist in the first place). What we usually say is if you're the OP, please don't post the word ***Thanks*** as a comment to an answer (if you like the answer, just upvote it; don't waste everyone's time with irrelevant "politeness").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The" is a definite article. It refers to a specific instance of something. So "the question" refers to the text at the top of the page that you are replying to.

In this case, "the question" is the text on this page that you wrote. I am answering "the question", or your question. I should not be typing here answering "any question", since that could mean I would be answering a question asked by someone else on another page and does not help you.

Or if I simply typed here "thank you", that doesn't help you either.

Comment: So, now you're answering _the_ question (because it was defined). But what _already-defined_ question that section is talking about?

Comment: If I understand the "Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most!" part correctly, the context is the following… Reader has just received some help (useful answers) from third-parties and now is thinking how to feedback. No specific question is defined at that point of time (except the reader's one). He can say "thanks" to the answerers that helped him, he can up-vote the best answers or (the best way) he can write an answer for **an** unrelated question (i.e. for some question that not necessary comes from those who helped him — just to "pay it forward").

Comment: And, if if won't bother you: what of the interpretations is actually correct: mine, my friend's or neither one?

Comment: You are incorrect in saying `No specific question is defined at that point of time`. "The question" is the one on the page - the one that started the page.

Comment: That paragraph is saying that if you feel the need to say thank you, don't create an answer or a comment that says "thank you". Instead, just up-vote the answer or comment that did help you.

Comment: So, mine friend's interpretation was right, and the meaning is "don't create a 'thank you' answer for your question after it gets resolved" — right?

Comment: Don't create a 'thank you' answer for your question at all, at any time - right.

Comment: But the context of that portion of text is that reader has just received some help (good answers) and is thinking how to feedback — right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.